# Do I need to install SimpleSamlPHP to work with Drupal

Tags: authentication, simplesamlphp

A client wants us to login using their login form. It connects and send a SAML SSO response that I can log. I am using working with Drupal, and I want to use simplesamlphp_auth module on drupal, but I don't know if they have SimpleSamlPHP set up on their end.

Do I need to set up SimpleSamlPHP as a SP on the website I am working on?

Is there a way to connect it with their login form?

Answer (score 0):

SAML is a protocol, like HTTP. That means you don't need to know what your client is using on their end. You have a SAML identity provider (the entity that sends a SAML authentication response, your client's webapp) and you have a service provider (your Drupal app). The SAML specification governs the interaction between these two entities.

Start with understanding how SAML works by reading http://identitymeme.org/doc/draft-hodges-learning-saml-00.html or http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0.html , then proceed to implementing SimpleSAMLPHP with Drupal